# Android Widget: doesn't update after certain period of time

Tags: android, widget, android-widget

Guys, I developed an android widget with an imageview and a single textview. It works fine, but after some updates the messages from my external file with the strings (quotes) doesn't update it. It just shows the image without any quote (message). Why is this happening?
He's my entire code. I'm a newbie.

Main.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class Main extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}


}
```

UpdateWidgetService.java

```
public class UpdateWidgetService extends Service {
private static final String TAG = CopyOfUpdateWidgetService.class.getSimpleName();

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    super.onStart(intent, startId);

    Log.d(TAG, "onStart started");

    // Create some random data
    Random random = new Random();

    AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(this.getApplicationContext());

    int[] appWidgetIds = intent.getIntArrayExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS);

    if (appWidgetIds.length > 0) {

        for (int widgetId : appWidgetIds) {
            List<String> qList = getListFromTxtFile("quotes.txt");
            int nextInt = random.nextInt(qList.size());

            RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);
            remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.widget_textview, qList.get(nextInt));
            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(widgetId, remoteViews);
        }
        stopSelf();
    }
    super.onStart(intent, startId);
}

public List<String> getListFromTxtFile(String txtFileName){

//  File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
// Get the text file
// File file = new File(sdcard,txtFileName);

AssetManager am = this.getAssets();

List<String> qList = new ArrayList<String>();

//Read text from file

try {
    InputStream is = am.open("quotes.txt");
          //BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    String line;

     // get data in text file line by line
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

        Log.d("line",line);

       qList.add(line);
    }
}
catch (IOException e) {
    //You'll need to add proper error handling here

    {Log.d("Error","There are an error");}
}
return qList;

}

}
```

WidgetQuotes.Java

```
public class WidgetQuotes extends AppWidgetProvider {

@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);

    // Build the intent to call the service
    RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), UpdateWidgetService.class);
    intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, appWidgetIds);

    // To react to a click we have to use a pending intent as the
    // onClickListener is
    // excecuted by the homescreen application
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(
            context.getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_textview, pendingIntent);

    // Finally update all widgets with the information about the click
    // listener
    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds, remoteViews);

    // Update the widgets via the service
    context.startService(intent);
}

public void onDeleted(Context context, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    //  Toast.makeText(context, "onDelete", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        super.onDeleted(context, appWidgetIds);
    }

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    super.onReceive(context, intent);
}
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.esmeralda"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
    <supports-screens android:smallScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true"    android:normalScreens="true"/>

   <application android:icon="@drawable/icone" android:label="@string/app_name">

    <receiver android:name="com.esmeralda.WidgetQuotes" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data 
            android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/widget_quotes_info" />
    </receiver>

    <service android:name="com.esmeralda.UpdateWidgetService"></service>
<activity
android:name="com.esmeralda.Main"
android:label="@string/app_name">
 <intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

 <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
 <action android:name="com.esmeralda.ACTION_WIDGET_CONFIGURE"/>
</intent-filter>
</activity>

</application>

</manifest>
```

widget_quotes_info.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:minWidth="294dp"
android:minHeight="250dp"
android:updatePeriodMillis="1800020"
android:initialLayout="@layout/widget" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should close BufferedReader after using it.

```
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

    Log.d("line",line);

    qList.add(line);
}

br.close();  // this is what you need to add
```

Comment: how can I do this? I'm a newbie... how can I close BufferedReader? Thanks in advance.

Comment: As I thought... I did this, but it still doesn't work :/

Comment: hm.. idk if it is importnat but you have super.onstart() method called 2 times.

Comment: Ok... I did this too... I removed one of super.onstart()method, but the problem contninues. :/